# Access TCP retransmitted byte count (and retransmitted packet count) for a given socket in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-core, tcp

I am wanting to use TCPListener / TCPClient with Async callbacks and IOCP for some TCP performance software.

What I would like to be able to do is obtain the number of bytes that have been retransmitted by the TCP stack for a currently active socket.

I note that mstcpip.h has the struct _TCP_INFO_v0.  This contains the field:

```
typedef struct _TCP_INFO_v0 {
  ...
  ULONG    BytesRetrans;
  ...
}
```

The MS documentation states:

> To get an instance of this structure, call the **WSAIoctl** or **LPWSPIoctl** function with the **SIO_TCP_INFO** control code.

I can't find a way to drill through the .NET objects with the necessary p/invoke calls to obtain this.  Can anyone assist with a code snippet using TCPClient as the starting point?

THANKS.

As extra for experts, it would also be nice to get the number of packets that were retransmitted, but I have not been able find a variable for that.  I guess that packet assembly and tracking would be occuring at a level below the tcp stack and in reality that two lost sequential packets could be retransmitted as a single packet and one lost packet could be retransmitted as two or even more packets - although I have never witnessed that in a packet trace - but then I have not been looking that hard either.

Comment: For an established TcpClient you should be able to do a `myTcpClient.Client.IOControl(SIO_TCP_INFO, BitConverter.GetBytes(0), outputArray); `, where SIO_TCP_INFO = -671088583 (0xD8000039) and `outputArray` is a byte array of some suitable size (128 should be enough). The outputArray will contain the structure you need, and the value you want can be retrieved by proper casting. IOControl itself will return the number of relevant bytes in the output array.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez Not '(0xD8000039)', but '(0xD8000027)' since the code is '_WSAIORW (IOC_VENDOR, 39)'. I.e. 39 is decimal, not hex.

Comment: @G.Vanem You´re right, missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comment provided by *C. Gonzalez* here is some code that seems to work.  It needs some testing on a lossy connection and a cleanup of the types and conversions.

```
    struct TCP_INFO_v0
    {
        public UInt32 State;
        public UInt32 Mss;
        public UInt64 ConnectionTimeMs;
        public byte TimestampsEnabled;
        public UInt32 RttUs;
        public UInt32 MinRttUs;
        public UInt32 BytesInFlight;
        public UInt32 Cwnd;
        public UInt32 SndWnd;
        public UInt32 RcvWnd;
        public UInt32 RcvBuf;
        public UInt64 BytesOut;
        public UInt64 BytesIn;
        public UInt32 BytesReordered;
        public UInt32 BytesRetrans;
        public UInt32 FastRetrans;
        public UInt32 DupAcksIn;
        public UInt32 TimeoutEpisodes;
        public byte SynRetrans;
    }

    // SIO_TCP_INFO as defined in winsdk-10/mstcpip.h
    readonly static int SIO_TCP_INFO = unchecked((int)0xD8000027);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 445);

        var outputArray = new byte[128];
        tcpClient.Client.IOControl(SIO_TCP_INFO, BitConverter.GetBytes(0), outputArray);

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(outputArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        TCP_INFO_v0 tcpInfo = (TCP_INFO_v0)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(TCP_INFO_v0));
        handle.Free();

        Console.WriteLine("Bytes retransmitted: {0}", tcpInfo.BytesRetrans);

    }
```